# Umformung von Relativsätzen und Partizpialkonstruktionen

Tags: relative-clause, past-participle, participle

Ich bin dabei, meine Kenntnisse der Umformung von Relativsätzen und Partizipialkonstruktionen zu prüfen.  Ich habe einige Fragen angesichts zweier Übungen.  Erstens, gibt das Buch den folgenden Satz, der umgeformt werden muss:

> Im Wagen, der bei Rot über die Kreuzung fuhr, saß niemand!

Meine Antwort war:

> Im bei Rot über die Kreuzung gefahrene Wagen saß niemand!

während die des Lehrbuchs folgendes war:

> Im bei Rot über die Kreuzung fahrenden Wagen saß niemand!

Ist meine Antwort auch korrekt?

Ähnlich bei

> Die Polizei hat sämtliche im Parkverbot abgestellten Wagen und Motorräder abgeschleppt.

Ich habe geantwortet

> Die Polizei hat sämtliche Wagen und Motorräder abgeschleppt, die im
> Parkverbot abgestellt wurden.

während das Lehrbuch folgendes sagt:

> Die Polizei hat sämtliche Wagen und Motorräder abgeschleppt, die im Parkverbot abgestellt waren.

Sind die Beiden korrekt, oder nur die Antwort des Buches?

Comment: Korrekt sind nur die Antworten des Buches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Im Wagen, der bei Rot über die Kreuzung fuhr, saß niemand!

Beide Handlungen stehen im Präteritum, also spielen sie beide zum aktuellen Erzählzeitpunkt der Geschichte. Richtig ist daher nur

> Im bei Rot über die Kreuzung fahrenden Wagen saß niemand!

Genauso für die Wirklichkeit:

> Im Wagen, der bei Rot über die Kreuzung fährt, sitzt niemand!
>
> Im bei Rot über die Kreuzung fahrenden Wagen sitzt niemand!

Oder zum Beispiel für eine Annahme:

> Im Wagen, der bei Rot über die Kreuzung fahren wird, wird niemand sitzen!
>
> Im bei Rot über die Kreuzung fahrenden Wagen wird niemand sitzen!

Beides findet gleichzeitig statt, also ist das Partizip I richtig.

Deinem Beispiel

> Im bei Rot über die Kreuzung gefahrenen Wagen saß niemand!

entspricht hingegen der Satz

> Im Wagen, der bei Rot über die Kreuzung gefahren war, saß niemand!

mit Plusquamperfekt und Präteritum.

In der Wirklichkeit ist das Paar hingegen Perfekt und Präsens.

> Im bei Rot über die Kreuzung gefahrenen Wagen sitzt niemand!
>
> Im Wagen, der bei Rot über die Kreuzung gefahren ist, sitzt niemand!

Und so weiter. Die eine Handlung findet vor der anderen statt, also ist das Partizip II richtig.

---

> Die Polizei hat sämtliche im Parkverbot abgestellten Wagen und Motorräder abgeschleppt.

Dieses Beispiel ist komplizierter. Das Partizip II markiert sowohl die Vorzeitigkeit als auch das Passiv. Und da gibt es natürlich sowohl Verlaufs- als auch Zustandspassiv

> Die Polizei hat sämtliche Wagen und Motorräder abgeschleppt, die im Parkverbot abgestellt waren. ← Zustandspassiv
>
> Die Polizei hat sämtliche Wagen und Motorräder abgeschleppt, die im Parkverbot abgestellt wurden. ← Verlaufspassiv

In diesem Zusammenhang passt das Zustandspassiv besser.

Comment: Das Verlaufspassiv ist im zweiten Beispiel falsch, da die Wagen, damit sie abgeschleppt werden können, abgestellt sein müssen. D.h. es muss ein Zustand des Abgestelltseins bestehen. Man kann kein Auto abschleppen, das noch abgestellt wird.

Comment: @Ben der Argumentation kann ich folgen, denoch denke ich, dass das zu eng gesehen ist. Will man ausdrücken, dass sie im Vorgang des Abstellens abgeschleppt werden, müsste man, um eindeutig zu sein, "Die Polizei hat Wagen abgeschleppt *während* sie im Parkverbot abgestellt wurden" formulieren.

Comment: Beim ersten Beispiel wäre es wichtig, zu erwähnen, was genau gleichzeitig stattfindet, damit man die Richtigkeit des Partizip I überhaupt begründen kann. Sind es das Fahren und das Rotsein oder das Fahren und das Sitzen? Im ersten Fall dürfte man den Satz *„Im Wagen, der bei Rot über die Ampel **fuhr**, **wird** gleich niemand mehr **sitzen**“* ebenfalls mit Partizip I umformulieren, denn Fahren und Rotsein finden gleichzeitig statt; im zweiten Fall dürfte man das nicht, denn Fahren und Sitzen finden zu unterschiedlichen Zeiten statt.

Answer (score 0):

> Im Wagen, der bei Rot über die Kreuzung fuhr, saß niemand!

Im Relativsatz ist *der*, also *Wagen*, das  Subjekt. Daher muß das Partizip I gewählt werden, da nur dort das mit dem Partizip verbundene Nomen dem Subjekt des zugrundeliegenden Verbs entspricht. Das Verb *fahren* existiert in einer intransitiven Variante *(der Wagen fährt)* und einer transitiven *(er fährt den Wagen)*, daher fällt der Unterschied nicht sofort auf. Aber z.B. bei *lenken*:

> der über die Kreuzung gelenkte Wagen ~ der Wagen, der über die Kreuzung gelenkt wird
>
> der den Wagen lenkende Fahrer ~ der Fahrer, der den Wagen lenkt

Bei

> sämtliche im Parkverbot abgestellten Wagen und Motorräder

sehe ich kein grammatisches Kriterium, um eine Paraphrase mit Zustandspassiv einer mit Vorgangspassiv vorzuziehen. Allerdings ist das Zustandspassiv nicht immer möglich.

> der geblitzte Autofahrer ~ der Autofahrer, der geblitzt wurde / ??war

Comment: "Im Wagen" ist keineswegs das Subjekt, sondern ein Dativobjekt! Das Subjekt ist "niemand"!

Comment: *Der* (das sich auf *Wagen* bezieht) ist das Subjekt im Relativsatz, von *fuhr*.